# green or white screen with processing + kinect

Tags: kinect, processing

I am in win7 x64 Pro

Kinect xbox 360 is connected and samples (openNI and NITE) run well. When i use Processing 2.1, sketch with kinect  run without error notification but there nothing on screen and he is gray or white... Yet all simple processing samples (without kinect) run well...What is wrong? I'm disappointed

intalled :

OpenNI-Win32-1.5.7-Dev.msi
NITE-Win32-1.5.2-Dev.msi
SensorKinect093-Bin-Win32-v5.1.2.1.msi
SimpleOpenNI 1.96
KinectSDK-v1.7
Ms Visual Studio 2012
Processing 2.1

I tried 
OpenNIx64-1.5.7-Dev.msi
NiTE-Windows-x64-2.0.0
Sensor-Win64-5.1.6.6
but I have same problem

kinect run well (all samples from openNI and Nite) but whith Processing 2.1 (or 2.0.3 and 1.5.1) It still doesn't work : nothing on screen (gray or white) without notification error.
All simple processing samples (without kinect) run well...

Thank you for your help

Comment: try downloading the previous version of simpleopenni

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use the J4K (Java for Kinect) library in Processing. J4K is an open-source library and communicates with the native Microsoft Kinect SDK. You can download the j4k-processing.zip from here: [j4k-processing.zip](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/download.php)

There is a Green-Screen example in the examples folder (you need to unzip the j4k-processing.zip) called example5_basicAugmentedReality. This example shows you in the middle of a simple 3D virtual scene. In addition there are other examples for 2D interaction, reading the values of the accelerometer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SimpleOpenNI 0.27 on Processing 1.5.1

You can download SimpleOpenNI 0.27 from [this link](https://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount)

if it didn't solve your problem. You should write more detail about your system that you use such as the version of SimpleopenNI, Kinect driver, etc